# How to pass environment variables to a remote application using LLDB?

Tags: lldb

I'm trying to debug a remote application that runs inside a Kubernetes Pod using LLDB. The remote application is started with the following command:

```
lldb-server platform --verbose --listen *:40007 --gdbserver-port 40008 --server
```

And I'm connecting to it from the client with the following commands:

```
lldb
platform select remote-linux
platform connect connect://remote_host:port
file /application
settings set target.inherit-env true
process launch
```

However, the debugged application does not have any environment variables set. How can I pass all system environment variables from the remote machine where the application is running on?

I tried setting `settings set target.inherit-env true` but there are still no environment variables present. I know that it is possible to set environment variables using the lldb `env` command, but since the environment variables are coming from Kubernetes config maps I don't know them in advance.

Comment: target.inherit-env is not what you want.  That setting says the target process should inherit lldb's environment.  The way this works with `debugserver` (the Darwin equivalent of `lldb-server g` is that if you pass the program to debugserver along with the listening port, it will launch the program with it's environment, which is what you want.  You might try that with `lldb-server g host:port my_program` then in lldb do `gdb-remote host::port` and then when you connect, the process will be stopped at its entry point with the right env.

Comment: But if you're so motivated, please file an issue with https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues, using the remote side's environment really should be the default behavior for remote debugging.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it with `lldb-server g` and in this case the remote environment is passed to the application indeed. I didn't expect this to be an issue with lldb but I'm happy to file an issue on github in this case.